# Android apps downloaded to emulator aren't working

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm working with a `GenyMotion emulator`, Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.2 if it matters.
I downloaded two apps, `Facebook` and `Facebook Messanger`, both seem to be installed fine on the device but when I tried to run them I got `unfortunately <app name> has stopped`.
I thought maybe it will happened with all apps so I downloaded an app called "Battery" just to be sure but this app worked fine.